# subsetting a dataframe in R with two steps

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
df
   name  direction to   
   <chr> <fct>     <chr>
 1 A     ->        B    
 2 A     ->        X    
 3 B     ->        X    
 4 B     ->        Y    
 5 C     ->        B    
 6 C     ->        Y    
 7 S     ->        T    
 8 T     ->        C    
 9 W     ->        Y    
10 X     ->        W    
11 Y     NA        NA
```

Step 1. I first want to subset the dataframe to only include values that either have X or Y in the columns `name` and `to`.

```
df %>% dplyr::select(name,direction,to) %>% filter(name %in% c('X','Y') | to %in% c('X','Y'))

  name  direction to   
  <chr> <fct>     <chr>
1 A     ->        X    
2 B     ->        X    
3 B     ->        Y    
4 C     ->        Y    
5 W     ->        Y    
6 X     ->        W    
7 Y     NA        NA
```

Step 2. From there, I want to get any other connections that match with any of the unique values in `name` from `df` in Step 1. For example, the unique values in `name` are A,B,C,W,X,Y after Step 1. I want to get all observations in the original dataset (without filtering) where any of these values are in the `name` column from the original dataset `df`. In this example, observations 1 (C->B) and 5 (A->B) from the original dataframe would be added to the subset.

**Expected output:**

```
  name  direction to   
  <chr> <fct>     <chr>
1 A     ->        X    
2 A     ->        B
3 B     ->        X    
4 B     ->        Y 
5 C     ->        B   
6 C     ->        Y    
7 W     ->        Y    
8 X     ->        W    
9 Y     NA        NA
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```r
df %>% dplyr::select(name,direction,to) %>% filter(name %in% c('X','Y') | to %in% c('X','Y')) -> dfTmp
df[df$name %in% (dfTmp$name),]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `if_any` to loop over the 'name', 'to' to return a logical vector, subset the 'name' and create a logical vector with `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(name %in% name[if_any(c(name, to), ~ . %in% c('X', 'Y' ))])%>%
   as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  name  direction to   
  <chr> <chr>     <chr>
1 A     ->        B    
2 A     ->        X    
3 B     ->        X    
4 B     ->        Y    
5 C     ->        B    
6 C     ->        Y    
7 W     ->        Y    
8 X     ->        W    
9 Y     <NA>      <NA>
```

Usually, `if_any` is used in `filter` to return rows when either one of the columns looped matches the condition i.e. here we loop over 'name' , 'to', check whether the column have 'X', 'Y' for each row.  If one of the column have that value, the row is returned.  The `if_any` returns a logical vector, so use that to subset (`[`) the 'name' elements and then create the logical vector with `%in%` on the original 'name' column

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "S", "T", 
"W", "X", "Y"), direction = c("->", "->", "->", "->", "->", "->", 
"->", "->", "->", "->", NA), to = c("B", "X", "X", "Y", "B", 
"Y", "T", "C", "Y", "W", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Comment: What exactly does this do? `if_any(c(name, to), ~ . %in% c('X', 'Y' ))`. More specifically I'm confused with what `~.` is doing.

Comment: @Eisen I updated the post. The `~` is standard notation in tidyverse for lambda function.  It can be otherwise wrriten as `function(x) x`